What do I need to configure reverse DNS?
I've set up PTR record on the DNS server of our organisation. Reverse lookup works on our network, but from a different network, it does not work.
It seems to me that something needs to be done on the regional Internet registry RIR's side.
I have no  idea how to get in touch with them and then why would they do what I want?
Can I just configure PTR records and if I did it correctly it will just work?
Do I need the RIR to do something?
Is it how everyone is doing it?
PS: i'm comfortable with DNS but reverse DNS is kind of confusing to me for now (I'm new to it).

Your ISP should own the PTR zones. Have you contacted them?

@GregAskew no I haven't we have public IP adresses and our own DNS server on BIND.

You have to really own that IP to be able to set PTRs, as Greg said, if you are not registered as a owner in IANA or RIPE for example(based on your location), you don't have access to the root dns servers which are responsible for reverse records on public IP addresses. In this case your ISP is in charge of that.

@ZhivkoZhelev I'm in Africa, so I guess AFRINIC is our Regsitry,  So if understand well There's no way around the registry, but my ISP is the bridge to the registry ?  What if they have no clue about all this. Am I doomed ?   What do you mean by "own" ? we pay our ISP for these IP addresses, does that mean we own them ? or what does it take to own IP addresses ?

@ZhivkoZhelev Also i'd like to know if the behavior I described in my question is normal and to be expected (reverse lookup working in our network but not outside)  ? or is it all wrong and the PTR records should be setup on my ISP's side ?

@Xsmael what you described is normal. The PTR record that you set inside your own network, even if it is a publicly visible DNS, is only visible within your network; reverse DNS can only be set by the people who own your IP address, and you're only renting it from them (your ISP, not your registrar). Your ISP is who you are paying for your internet access.

@Xsmael You are correct, it's not wrong to have PTRs locally, nothing can go wrong, but if you want these reverse records to be visible publicly, you will have to contact your ISP. Technically, what is happening is that they will do the same(the might be using bind as well) but their(ISP) dns server is  a "special one" and other dns servers will fetch this PTR records from it and propagate them to the public accessible servers.

Thank you all, this is really helpfull!

@ZhivkoZhelev I'd like to know what makes the ISPs DNS servers special, and how other DNS servers synchronises with them.

Nothing about your ISPs servers is special.  You need to spend more time reading up on how DNS works.  Anyway either the root, or parent for a given zone delegated authority to your ISP.  Anyway, it all starts from the root servers, and delegated from there depending on the zone.

@Xsmael, keep in mind that there are two kinds of "the ISP's DNS servers". The ones which you use to make DNS queries (recursive servers) are not the same as the ones which host rDNS data, or regular DNS data (authoritative servers).

@Xsmael By "special" I mean that this servers are registered in afrinic(in your case) and they become trusted. So other registered servers can use them as a source of truth.

Reverse DNS is essentially the same as DNS. In case of a normal domain, say example.org, the registrar of .org will reply that example.org is handled by your DNS server.
With reverse DNS, it's the same. A reverse record (for IPv4) looks like 1.0.18.198.in-addr.arpa.. The reason why it's reversed, is to allow subnetting. The root servers will in this case have a pointer to 198.in-addr.arpa.. The NS for 198.in-addr.arpa. may further delegate 18.198.in-addr.arpa to someone else.
The result of this is that the owner of the block is delegated access. There's mechanisms to delegate subnets not aligned to octet boundaries. But in short; you need to work with your ISP.

you mean the registry instead of registrar? right ?

Thank you very much, all the comments and and answers helped me clear some confusion, now i gotta read more on rDNS cause now i can better understand it.
